# the Devise timeout message doesn't correspond to the users set I18n.locale

Tags: devise, session-timeout, rails-i18n

In my rails app  I set the `I18n.locale` based the on the subdomain using a `before_filter` in the application controller as well as in any controller that inherits from a devise controller(Confirmations, Password and Sessions controllers).

```
def set_locale
  unless Rails.env.test?
    sd = request.subdomain.to_s[-2..-1]
    I18n.locale = I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s).include?(sd) ? sd : I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

I've also included the corresponding devise language files and all of my devise messages are showing up in the correct language except when there is a sessions timeout.  In these instances the message shows up randomly, sometimes in the correct language and sometimes not.  I believe it isn't looking at the current subdomain to set the language but is using whatever the locale was set as the last time a request to the server was made.

I thought this might have to do with the [Devise FailureApp](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated) so in lib/custom_failure.rb which inherits from the Devise FailureApp I set the locale there as well but that still didn't work.

I am currently using a hack where I've set the `devise.failure.timeout` message to an empty string and if I detect an empty string in a flash notice then I set `flash[:alert] = t('devise.failure.timedout)`. Timedout is a custom devise message thats set to what `devise.failure.timeout` is supposed to be before I hacked it.

Is this an issue with Devise or is there a Devise controller that I'm missing where I need to set the locale, any help will be greatly appreciated.